concat or merge to data frame tables that do not have primary keys
I have 2 data frames
    Name    Middle Name Last Name
0   Ambar   Klein   Liam
1   Maya    J   Jacobson
2   Steve   Knowles Gomez
3   Sam l   Smith
4   Gomez   John    Smith
5   Mical   M   Mason     


Name    Last Name
0   Smith   Klein
1   Sams    Peter
2   Betts   Knowles

I am trying to concat these 2 data frames that relatively have the same data but dont necessarily have any joining fields. My goal is to have all the data in one DF rather than having to work from multiple dfs.
I currently have the following code, but when i concat all the columns are not concat into one table, but rather some column are missing and show up in the row.
test_li = []

 

for test_filename in test:

test_df = pd.read_excel(test_filename, index_col=None, header=None)

test_li.append(test_df)



test_frame = (

            pd.concat(test_li , axis=0, ignore_index=True)

                .dropna(how="all") #to get rid of the eventual extra rows above each header

                .drop_duplicates() #to get rid of the cumulated duplicated headers

                .T.set_index(0).T #to make the first row as header of the dataframe

                # .drop(list(df.filter(regex=string)),axis=1,inplace=True)

        )

test_frame = test_frame.loc[:,test_frame.columns.notnull()]

test_frame

the above code produces the current output: However in row 13 you can see that one of my tables had Only the first and last name as columns whereas the second table had first, middle and last name. And during the concat process, the headers from one of the tables is converted into row 13.
Current output
Name    Middle Name Last Name
1   Ambar   Klein   Liam
2   Maya    J   Jacobson
3   Steve   Knowles Gomez
4   Sam l   Smith
5   Gomez   John    Smith
6   Mical   M   Mason
12  NaN NaN t
13  Name    Last Name   NaN
14  Smith   Klein   NaN
15  Sams    Peter   NaN
16  Betts   Knowles NaN

I would like to be able to concat my dfs and have the output in the format below, and to where all the columns from both dfs are merged together.
Desired Output
Name      Middle Name   Last Name
0   Ambar   Klein      Liam
1   Maya    J         Jacobson
2   Steve   Knowles     Gomez
3   Sam l   Smith
4   Gomez   John    Smith
5   Mical   M       Mason
6   Smith   -        Klein
7   Sams    -      Peter
8   Betts   -      Knowles


You should import your data with a correct header. Use the default header=0 parameter of read_excel, not header=None:
test_li = []
for test_filename in test:
    test_li.append(pd.read_excel(test_filename, index_col=None))

Then a simple concat will work directly:
test_frame = (pd.concat(test_li, ignore_index=True)
                .dropna(how='all') # optional
                .drop_duplicates() #
              )


if I understood your issue, you can have a specified set of columns that your final dataframe must have and then compare based on that. I created a test example:
data = {"Name": ["Ambar", "Maya", "Steve"], "Middle": ["Klein", "J", "Knowles"], "Last": ["Liam", "Jacobson", "Gomez"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {"Name": ["Smith", "Sams", "Betts"],  "Last": ["Klein", "Peter", "Knowles"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

column_names = {"Name", "Middle", "Last"}

test_li = [df1, df2]
for test_df in test_li:
    df_col_list = test_df.columns.tolist()
    if set(df_col_list) != column_names:
        for colname in column_names:
            if colname not in df_col_list:
                test_df[colname] = "-"
                print(colname, colname in df_col_list)


display(df1)
display(df2)

df3 = pd.concat(test_li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
display(df3)

OUTPUT
Name    Middle  Last
0   Ambar   Klein   Liam
1   Maya    J   Jacobson
2   Steve   Knowles Gomez

Name    Last    Middle
0   Smith   Klein   -
1   Sams    Peter   -
2   Betts   Knowles -

Name    Middle  Last
0   Ambar   Klein   Liam
1   Maya    J   Jacobson
2   Steve   Knowles Gomez
3   Smith   -   Klein
4   Sams    -   Peter
5   Betts   -   Knowles

I used sets so we don't compare order of the fields (just in case).If the columns don't match, then you can add the missing column.
Based on your code it would be something like:
test_li = []
column_names = {"Name", "Middle", "Last"}

for test_filename in test:
   test_df = pd.read_excel(test_filename, index_col=None, header=None)
   for test_df in test_li:
      df_col_list = test_df.columns.tolist()
      if set(df_col_list) != column_names:
         for colname in column_names:
            if colname not in df_col_list:
               test_df[colname] = "-"
               print(colname, colname in df_col_list)

   test_li.append(test_df)

I'm not sure if this will work on all your files as I don't have the context of the structure of all files, but it might help.
